# AS3 repeat same code in a vertor which has 2500 objects

Tags: actionscript-3

This is my problem, i'm making a path finding program 'jump point search algorithm'. And i need to reset every node (object) in the vector 40 by 40 vector so 2500 nodes, so i need to do the following

```
 //* some type of loop*//
 {
 node.is_been_on = false;
 }
```

But my path finding may happen 5 times every seconds with a few objects. So that a lot of looping.

What is the CPU friendly way to do this, or another solution which means i don't need to do it.

One of my friends saying that i should make a 40 by 40 boolean array and having the is_been_on variable it, so i would refer to that and not the node, would that be better?

Thanks for reading, and i hope you can help

Answer (score 0):

The most simple idea is to reset only the nodes that you've changed - store them in different array and iterate only it - JPS should modify only a small part of the given nodes.

The idea of your friends is not better, since you will still iterate over all nodes, and modify each value. The values of the node are also boolean (or at least I hope so), so you win nothing but having second array (vector) of values.

Either way I don't find it that bad to modify bool values, but if you really need to optimize (which I find great) - go with "reset what's changed" - can't imagine better one.

Comment: lets say I have a array called "been_on_array" and rather than making them all false by using a for loop or something. I just say been_on_array = been_on_array_ready, so I don't need to say to every value its false because i have a backup array which all the values are false. Is that a better idea?

Comment: I don't understand what do you want to optimize.
Say you need 2500 items in array. 500 of them are `true` and you want to make them false.
I think it's best to save those 500 in another array and iterate over them (total 500 calls to push in this array on change, 500 to iterate and set to false, total 1000).
Your solution needs to create a new array with ANOTHER 2500 elements. (2500 iterations to populate). And 500 to set to true = 3000. After the first reset, you need to create NEW array (again 2500 iterations). 

Reusing is the core of optimization :)
Hope this explanation makes sense.

Comment: let me example my plan better (Thanks for the help btw) I will make a array called "DO_DONT_CHANGE_BEEN_ON" so this is a multidimensional array which have all 40 by 40 value equal to false. Then i will copy this array and called it "TMP_BEEN_ON" so in this array i will make value equal true, once im done. I don't need "TMP_BEEN_ON", so i will just make it equal to DO_DONT_CHANGE_BEEN_ON, but im not too sure if i can copy it without  binding it to the original. So This should make it so i never need to iterate them, well thats the plan.

Comment: You said it right - in order to have second array and not modify the first one, you need to duplicate. That's what I said in my prev comment - 2500 iterations to populate). You can do it with splice, but it won't be much faster, it's again creating a whole new set of elements. And you will need to do it every time you start a new round. Creation is one of the slowest operations and you need to stick to reusing as much as you can. Make a simple test with getTimer(), and check how fast you populate/iterate 500, and on the other hand duplicate the whole array. Should show you the difference..

Answer (score -1):

But why do you recalculate path 5 times every second? You have graph with a size 40x40, by the help of [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm) or another one algorithm, you will be able find correct path. As you calculate path, you don't recalculate it again, only if you have dynamic obstacles in the game.

If you don't know how to implement pathfinding algorithm in AS3 project. There are [several ready solutions](http://www.as3gamegears.com/category/path-finding/)

Comment: In my game there a quite a few dynamic obstacles. And I would like to build it my self, my path finder works but i'm trying to optimize it, if possible.